# gulp-ruby-haml Error: Cannot find module

Tags: ruby, gulp

I'm trying to install and use [gulp-ruby-haml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-haml/).

I have Ruby installed and have run `gem install haml` successfully.

My `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var haml = require('gulp-ruby-haml');

// Compile Haml into HTML
gulp.task('haml', function() {
  gulp.src('./haml/*.haml', {read: false}).
       pipe(haml()).
       pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});

// The default task (runs all designated tasks on 'gulp')
gulp.task('default', ['haml']);
```

However, when I run `gulp` on the project I receive this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-ruby-haml'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ben/projects/portfolio2/gulpfile.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Sorry if this is a simple fix - I'm not sure.

FYI I'm not using rails on this project. It is a static project with haml compiled by gulp-ruby-haml and gulp (Ubuntu OS). I got [gulp-haml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-haml/) working but I didn't like the formatting requirements.

Answer (score 1):

gulp-ruby-haml is a Node.js module.

That means you need to run `npm install gulp-ruby-haml`